# Assigning Data from SQL Server 2000 Database to Strings

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I am new to C#. My Database table with two columns, A column and B column. Column A has unique static values and column b has random values, so I am running a query to get all these data but now want to store each row of data to strings that are already defined that matches column A.

So In others words, my strings will look like the following once done

```
String first (same name as in A column) = B column; (Row 1 value)
string second (same name as in A column) = B column; (Row 2 value) 
string third (same name as in A column) = B column; (Row 3 value)
```

I was also thinking of using XML as an alternative, so exporting data to XML and the reading from XML and still converting them to strings so I can use them in my application, but was not able to find solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string connStr = "Enter Your connection String Here";
            string SQL = "Enter Your SELECT Here";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, connStr);

            DataTable ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            ds.WriteXml("FileName", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Comment: thank you but, that only creates the xml file which I already done but if going the XML route, I will still need to read the values from the XML and store each value to matching string

Comment: Maybe I will post an example of what I mean